# :nth-last-child(1) with row or column reverse?

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to select the last item of a list even if that list is flex-reversed.

**Example:**

I have a list. I want the background color in the last element at red. So, on the first list, it's ok. On the second list, that list is revert, isn't ok because the last element is "1" and not "5". So I create a "fix" class who replaces the CSS values to make the effect.

```css
.list {
  background-color: green; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.list div:nth-last-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.rev {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.rev-fix div:nth-last-child(1) {
  background-color: initial;
}

.rev-fix div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="list rev">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="list rev rev-fix">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

I don't think it's the best way to do it. So how I can select the last element even if the list is reverted with the good practices on CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, pseudo-selectors run in DOM order. You could make use of the `:not` pseudo selector though to skip targeting any flex-reversed elements. This will remove reliance on a second class to fix the applied css

```css
.list {
  background-color: green; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.rev {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.list:not(.rev) div:last-child {
  background: red;
}

.rev div:first-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="list rev">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `.rev-fix`, but your intuition is correct – you do need to change behavior when it's reversed. `last-child` or `nth-last-child` refer to the HTML order, not the layout. Insead of the `.rev-fix` flips use this:

```
.list.rev div:last-child {
  background-color: initial;
}

.list.rev div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Also, be careful with the `.list div` selector..., you should set a class for that `div` type of thing, or use `.list > div` to make sure you're not targeting all divs in that subtree.